# Unable to find a specification for `Google Places`

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to add Google Places SDK to my xcode project but keep getting the error

```
Unable to find a specification for `GooglePlacePicker`
```

This is my pod file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Restaurant' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Restaurant
 pod 'GooglePlaces'
 pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
 pod 'GoogleMaps'


  target 'RestaurantTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing


  end

  target 'RestaurantUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

The funny thing is, if I remove 'GooglePlaces' and 'GooglePlacePicker' it installs the 'GoogleMaps' perfectly fine.